# Supergroup of Complex numbers modulo 3.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the group $\mathbb{Z_3^*[i]}=\{a+bi\text{|} a,b \in \mathbb{Z_3}\}-\{0\}$ a subgroup of a larger group? I figure that it is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z[i]}=\{a+bi|a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}-\{0\}$.

I proved by deriving $a(c-d)=b(c+d)$ from $(a+bi)\times(c+di)=(0+0i)$, that the only way to obtain a product of $(0+0i) \text{ is if I multiply by } (0+0i)$ which is not an element of either group.

I then had to prove that there could be no repeated elements in a row or column of a cayley table, preserving the structure of my subgroup, so I derived the system of equations $a(c-x)=b(d-y) \text{ and   } a(d-y)=b(x-c)$ from $(a+bi)\times(c+di)=(a+bi)\times(x+yi)$. Thus, in order for the left side of the original equation to equal the right side, x must equal c, and d must equal y, proving that these two "different" elements are actually the same element.

I believe that proves that my group is a subgroup of complex numbers, but I'm just looking for some verification.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.  You seem to be assuming that it is.

Comment: Why isn't $\mathbb{Z_3}$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What 3 elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ do you think constitute a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: We just went over isomorphisms recently, but I think I am catching on. They do not have the same structure in anyway, is that correct? Because one is infinite, and the other is a repeating modulo 3?

Comment: That's correct.  (See answer for more details in a moment).

Comment: Thanks, Ted. I appreciated the help. I've been stressing over this for hours. So it seems that there is no larger group.

Comment: It's not correct to say "there is no larger group".  Any group can be embedded in a larger group ($G$ is subgroup of $G \times \mathbb{Z}_2$).  To get a more meaningful question, you have to put some restrictions on *how* the smaller group is embedded in the larger group (and/or some restrictions on what kind of larger group you want).  Usually when this kind of question arises, you want to embed a group in some larger group that you already understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_3$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, which you seem to be assuming.  Instead, $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a *quotient* of $\mathbb{Z}$.  There is a surjective map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_3$, sending an integer to its residue modulo 3.  It's important not to confuse subgroups with quotients.

An intuitive picture which may be useful is this.  Suppose you have some image file which is too large for your purposes.  There are two things you can do to make it smaller:

(1) Crop the image, which completely removes some parts of the picture, but the remaining parts stay exactly the same.  This corresponds to the idea of *subgroups*.

(2) Keep the entire image, but reduce the resolution.  In doing so, you have not completely destroyed any part of the image, but lost some fine-grained details.  This corresponds to the idea of *quotients*.

(Source for this idea: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/some-notes-on-group-extensions/ paragraph starting with "An analogy would be to that of digital images")

To answer your original question, any group can be embedded in a larger group ($G$ is subgroup of $G \times \mathbb{Z}_2$), but this is probably not the kind of answer you are looking for.  Usually when this kind of question arises, you want to embed a group in some larger group that you already understand.  (If you don't understand $G$, how will you understand $G \times \mathbb{Z}_2$?)  To get a more meaningful question, you have to put some restrictions on how the smaller group is embedded in the larger group and/or some restrictions on what kind of larger group you want.